# drawing tableaus for predicate logic?

Tags: predicate-logic, first-order-logic

I'm  a bit confused about the rules. I know for existential ones, you replace the variable with a new constant and for universal you replace it with a closed term. $\forall x A(x) \to A(t)$ if $t$ is substitutable for $x$ in $A$.

But i dont understand what it means by a closed term. and how do u know if its substitutable? can u replace it with other variables used in the original formula, functions, new constants? any detailed examples would be great!

thanks

Comment: See Raymond Smullyan, [First-Order Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=kgvhQ-oSZiUC&pg=PA54) (1968), page 54.

Comment: For an example, you can see this [post](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1254172/semantic-tableaux-cant-show-sequent-is-valid).

Answer (score 1):

A *term* is a *variable* or a  *constant* or it is built up from already existsing terms and a *function* symbols.

A *closed* term is a term without variables: terms have no quantifiers; thus, an occurrence of a variable in a term is always free.

Examples of *closed* terms in the language of arithmetic are the *constants* $0$ and $1$ and the term $0+1$, built up from them with the function $+$.

If a term $t$ is *closed* it is always *substitutable* for $x$ in $∀xA(x) \to A(t)$.

The proviso about *substitutability* [for a formal definition, see: Herbert Enderton, [A Mathematical Introduction to Logic](https://books.google.it/books?id=dVncCl_EtUkC&pg=PA113) (2nd ed - 2001), page 113] is required in order to avoid that, substituting a term $t$ with a variable inside (e.g. $y$) in place of $x$ into $\forall x A(x)$, the (free) occurrence of $y$ into $t$ will be "captured" by a quantifier $\forall y$ present into $A$.

If $t$ is closed, there are no variables, and thus no free occurrences of them, and thus no danger of "unwanted capturing".

Consider the following example:

> $\forall x \exists y \ (x < y)$,

which is true in $\mathbb N$.

Here $A(x)$ is $\exists y \ (x < y)$ and, according to the definition, $t$ is **not** substitutable for $x$ in $A$. Why ?

Because the result of the substitution would be:

> $\exists y \ (y < y)$

which is clearly false.

Comment: A key point of confusion is that "not substitutable" means "not substitutable according to the rules". Of course we *can* substitute anything we want, but sometimes this will change the truth value or provability of the expression, while if we make a change that follows the rules we will preserve the truth value or provability.

Comment: !Mauro - your answer is good - I upvoted it! I just wanted to throw in my 2p about the fact that "substitutable" means "legally substitutable", not just "could be substituted in principle". Sometimes I find that is a confusing point for students.